# WKHTMLTOPDF - Generating thumbnails for PDF

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

We have a PDF file and wanted to generate a thumbnail for same from the first page of the PDF. Is it possible using `wkhtmltopdf`?

We know GhostScript is an option to do, but we would like to explore more options.

We have already explored iTextSharp and it does not allow so.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware about wkhtmltopdf, but if you are a linux user, and, 
if you have installed  ImageMagick then it would be as simple as:

```
convert pdfname.pdf[1] thumbnail.png
```

Hope it helps!